# Connect from local PC to remote server with Docker web server

Tags: apache, docker, ssh, webserver

my Docker-Container is on my server. 
Via SSH I can connect to the server from my local PC.

```
ssh user@RemoteServerIP -p 3360
```

From there I can connect to the Docker container via SSH

```
ssh userRemoteServer@DockerContainerOnServerIP -p 22
```

A Apache Webserver is running on the Docker-Container.

How can I access the Webserver on my local computer?

Comment: please check if port 22 is exposed in your docker and make sure your docker is supporting ssh. You can also try to run /bin/bash or just sh to your docker container.

Answer (score 0):

from you server try to figure out which port the apache container is using.. you can use netstat command `sudo netstat -ntlp` usually in the `PID/Program name` docker port is `PID/docker-proxy` .

after you know which port apache container is using, then u can access it using `yourServerIP:ApacheContainerPort` from you local computer

assuming of course the way you exposing apache port inside container is correct.

Comment: I released Prot 22, 80 and 443 in the Docker container: `EXPOSE 22, 80, 443`. `netstat` does not show me the `PID/docker-proxy` on the remote server. The container runs correctly on the remote server.

Comment: when you configuring your apache,, what port u are using for the apache inside container..?did you see that port when u issue command `netstat` ?